# Displaying different objects in suggestion box of autocomplete richfaces

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, jboss6.x

I am facing an issue migrating a suggestionBox to richfaces 4 autocomplete which is a bit complex there are two objects Groups and People. The suggestion box should display both the objects or either of the two. I have attached the screenshot of the suggestionBox of how it looks. The groups will be shown below the 'Groups' label and people below the 'People' label. The object from the backingbean gives a list of both the objects. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<rich:autocomplete id="selTrainerOrGroup" minChars="2" mode="ajax"
                                  autocompleteMethod="#{backingBean.getFuzzySearch}" 
                                  var="trainersGroups" autofill="false" fetchValue="#{trainersGroups.name}">
                         <h:column>
                            <h:outputText value="#{trainersGroups.name}" />
                         </h:column>         
               </rich:autocomplete>
```

Comment: Not seeing any screenshot. If you want to make it look like a select with optgroups I don't think that's possible.

Comment: @Makhiel:  
I am able to invoke the method and get the response as well, but i dont see the values rendered on the page.

Comment: @Makhiel: I see the list when i change the mode to client, but not when i set the mode to ajax.

Comment: Have you checked if the method returns the correct data?

Comment: @Makhiel: Yes it returns the correct data. I see the response in the network tab of the console.

Comment: I still have not found solution for this, can somebody help on this.